# Proper SE Site To ask about stimulating brain by light (Optogenetics) with non surgical method

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I like to ask about stimulating brain by light (similar to Optogenetics) non surgical way by combinations of effectiveness of brain stimulation by light and none surgical stimulating brain methods.

i have seen this post :

[Non-Invasive Deep-Brain Stimulation with Optogenetics](https://www.osa-opn.org/home/newsroom/2018/february/non-invasive_deep-brain_stimulation_with_optogenet/)

which is used to newer infrared blue light to penetrating to brain skull and amplified by some nano chemical martial injected to the mouse brain .

so i found [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjGnMqRquzmAhXQiFwKHRXVAl8QFjACegQIZRAJ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fpmc%2Farticles%2FPMC4552256%2F&usg=AOvVaw0VFDUdzeaDUI9nVuQTA1zT) light wavelength could penetrate:

> the Near-infrared light (NIR) has shown promise in animal models of
>   both TBI and stroke. ... Our recent tissue studies demonstrate no
>   penetration of low level NIR energy through 2 mm of skin or 3 cm of
>   skull and brain. However, at 10–15 W, 0.45%–2.90% of 810 nm light
>   penetrated 3 cm of tissue.

and [this chart](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjci56nrOzmAhWQ3KQKHfKpDSAQjhx6BAgBEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FTissue-penetration-depths-of-various-wavelengths-Figure-courtesy-of-Wellman-Center-for_fig2_256835631&psig=AOvVaw3mfT5YXuIuBxcKyh4vub-W&ust=1578309393239639):

[image]

so could this penetrating be sorted to stimulating as surgical Optogenetics usages at brain.

so what SE sites are proper to ask this question?

Answer (score 4):

[Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) or [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) might be good candidates to ask questions about that topic.

Be sure to read the policies manifested in these sites' help-centers, to ask an *on-topic* question though.

Answer (score 3):

The [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/53901/49363) site returns the most hits for the [search term "Optogenetics"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Optogenetics).

Example:

- "[How does optogenetics work?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30203/49363)"

More importantly, you can see that the moderator uses the technique in his lab.

- "[How long does Lentivirus take to express in vivo mouse neurons?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/52596/49363)"

Comment: Thanks [@Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob), so one of finding mechanism for proper SE site is finding most hits rate of SE Sites, any education about how to do it?

Comment: @modern, the second link above. Type in a few words to search all our sites. Click "Advanced Search Help" link for the extra parameters.